# MVC Validation Summary manipulation with JS and Dynamic DOM elements

Tags: model-view-controller

I am adding fields after the page load and would like to know how I can interface my JS with .net's validation summary on MVC.

Does a simple way exist?

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method is to use jQuery and get the validation summary.

```
var ul = $("#validationSummary ul");
ul.append("&lt;li&gt;Custom Error Message&lt;/li&gt;")
```

as is done here: [link text](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/08/23/asp-net-mvc-jquery-validation-and-validationsummary.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net MVC with its server side and client side validations. 
Basically you need to apply rules for validation while defining a models (Class Files)

Following is link which will describe Model Validation in ASP.NET MVC.

[Model Validation in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-validation-to-the-model)