# What's the recommended way to display errors from JavaScript (jQuery) in ASP.NET MVC 3 views?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, client-side-validation

I submit a form to my ASP.NET MVC 3 server through a JavaScript handler (I use jQuery), and receive error responses from the server in another JavaScript handler. What I'm wondering is how I should display error messages, resulting from the form submission, in the view? I would prefer using some standard ASP.NET MVC 3 idiom/construct.

**EDIT**

Note that I want to display error messages from the server, received in a JavaScript error handler function.

Comment: do you mean validation errors? or error status codes in response? or what?

Comment: @Michael Sagalovich A JavaScript error event handler is called with an error message from the server, I want to display this error message to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go the pure MVC way: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Scroll down to "Enabling Client-Side Validation."

In your View you'll have code that looks like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
```

**UPDATE**

Seems OP is interested in custom messaging.  There isn't any MVC construct for this sort of custom messaging.  Your best bet is to just create your own messaging area and write messages to it in your callback function.  Shouldn't be too complicated!

```
$.ajax(..., function(data) {
    $('#errors').append('<p>' + data + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: I have client-side validation already. What I'm asking is how to display errors that I *receive from the server*.

Comment: Well there isn't any built-in construct for custom messaging between your JS and the server.  You'll want to just create a div (say with the ID of "errors" or something equally intuitive) and just write messages there manually.

Comment: I guess the error div creation is the interesting bit. Maybe there's some jQuery API for creating a suitably styled error div?

Comment: jQuery can create elements, sure, but I'd just either create a partial view or just write the HTML yourself direct on the page where you want it and style it with CSS.  It's just like creating any other element on your page.  Learn about partial views here: http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/

Comment: I ended up with just adding an initially hidden div to the view, in which I display server errors. I remember Rails having some built-in support for displaying errors in the view, I guess I wish had some ready-made solution like that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using jQuery validate that comes with MVC solution templates, in your javascript handler you will have to add errors to the validator. There is a `showErrors` [method on validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/showErrors).

**On the client side**:

```
var formSubmitCallback = function(result){
  var validator = $(this).data('validator');
  if(!result.IsValid && validator)
      validator.showErrors(result.Errors); // uses jquery validator to highlight the fields
  // process the rest of the result here
  // if result.Action == ActionTypes.Redirect
  //     location.href = result.Url
  // etc
}
```

Now I had to standardize the result object from the server to return a json object formatted with `{ "FieleName": "Error Message" }`. I built a few `Controller` and `ViewModel` extension on the server side to accomplish that.

**On the server side**:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(Model someModel){
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
        // save
    else
        // other stuff

    // always return this.AjaxSubmit.
    // Extension function will add Errors, and IsValid to the response data
    return this.AjaxSubmit(new ClientAction{
        Action = ClientActionType.Redirect,
        Url = "/Some/Redirect/Route"
    });
}
```

*Note*: looking back on this now I did write a bit of custom code to make it work. I will eventually add the client and server code, together with examples on github. But this is the general idea.

**The server classes and extension you will need are below**

```
// GetAllErrors is a ModelState extension to format Model errors for Json response
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetAllErrors(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    var query = (from state in modelState
                 where state.Value.Errors.Count > 0
                 group state by state.Key into g
                 select new
                 {
                     FieldName = g.Key,
                     FieldErrors = g.Select(prop => prop.Value.Errors).First().Select(prop => prop.ErrorMessage).ToList()
                 });

    return query.ToDictionary(k => k.FieldName, v => string.Join("<br/>", v.FieldErrors));
}

// Controller result extension to return from actions
public static JsonResult AjaxSubmit(this Controller controller, ClientAction action)
{
    if (controller == null) return new JsonResult { Data = action };

    var result = new AjaxSubmitResult
    {
        Errors = controller.ModelState.GetAllErrors(),
        IsValid = controller.ModelState.IsValid,
        ClientAction = action
    };

    return new JsonResult{ Data = result };
}

// Action to perform on the client after a successful, valid response
public class ClientAction
{
    public ClientActionType Action { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Function { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Updatables { get; set; }
}

public enum ClientActionType
{
    Redirect,
    Ajax,
    Function,
    Modal,
    Message,
    FunctionAndMessage
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate how I should produce a validation summary from my JavaScript function?

Comment: $(this).data('validator') is undefined for me, even though jquery.validate.min.js is included.

Comment: `$(this)` in my example is referring to the form. if the form has is validated by jQuery it will have a data('validator') instance. In your case, just try `$('#form-id-here')`

Comment: I see, I got hold of the validator, but what format does validator.showErrors expect? I have simply an error message as a string.

Comment: `{ "FieleName": "Error Message" }` see [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/showErrors)

Answer (score 1):

The server should respond with a standardized message. That message could contain a complete error message (HTML) which you can then display in an empty div that is part of your `_Layout` page:

```
function(response) {
  if(response.Status === "error") {
    $("#errorContainer").html(response.ErrorHtml);
  } else {
    // the success handler
  }
}
```

The upside is that you can perform a rather standardized error message rendering on the server. Of course you could also display these as js popups / modal dialogs, etc.

The formatting of the error message is done via CSS that can be applied quite generically to `#errorContainer` and its contents.

You might want to argue that it is cleaner to respond with plain text from the server and add any html in the client via JS. That is possible, too, and probably works better with 'real' REST APIs. However, it does not allow to use formatted error messages (e.g. with links, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I answered something similar in the past on this for adding the error messages.

[MVC Validation Summary manipulation with JS and Dynamic DOM elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520027/mvc-validation-summary-manipulation-with-js-and-dynamic-dom-elements)

Since you want errors coming back from the server in what I'm assuming is your already known javascript method, simply add

```
var ul = $("#validationSummary ul"); ul.append("<li>Custom Error Message</li>")
```

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll check it out when back at work on Monday.

Comment: #validationSummary is apparently not rendered by MVC, probably because there aren't any errors known to MVC.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is:

Create base controller class and override the OnException handler

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            // add my own status code
            Response.StatusCode = 550;
            // write the error message to the response
            Response.Write(filterContext.Exception.Message);
            // mark the exception as handled
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }

        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

On the client side on document ready I register global handler for ajax errors

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
    error:function(x,e){
        if(x.status==0){
           alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
        }else if(x.status==404){
           alert('Requested URL not found.');
        }else if(x.status==550){ // <----- THIS IS MY CUSTOM ERROR CODE --------
           alert(x.responseText);
        }else if(x.status==500){
           alert('Internel Server Error.');
        }else if(e=='parsererror'){
           alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
        }else if(e=='timeout'){
           alert('Request Time out.');
        }else {
           alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
        }
    }
});
});
```

You can of course tweak this methods to suite your needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: the OP was to receive form submission errors, which would generally be status code 200, with some message with it, not 500 exceptions. In this case 200 results won't be ajax errors.

Comment: Error reception is not part of the problem, as I already have a callback receiving error messages from the server, the problem is only to display the messages. I'm not sure if I want to display a message box (with alert).

Comment: Adam Tuliper - Error should mean something different than status code 200 and should be (usually) handled in a centralized function (better code maintainability). Code 200 should invoke the specific success handler, while returning status code different than 200 means that something is wrong and should be handled differently

Comment: aknuds1 - You asked for a specific asp.net mvc construct which I provided as a full solution in case somebody finds it useful. In the example I use alert as the easiest solution. Once you have the mechanism for handling errors, you can implement your own info dialogs (jqueryUI, fancybox), maybe slideDown a div on the top of the screen, return json and modify the submitting form accordingly, etc... However that is not ASP.NET MVC issue. I will be happy to update the answer with some of the mentioned solutions, if you are intersted.

Comment: I don't need any mechanism for delivering the error status from the server, as this is already in place (via SignalR). What I'm after is how to display error information in the view. If the solution doesn't make use of MVC facilities, I'm fine with that :)